# Finite difference on matrices

Tags: matrix-equations

This question relates closely to [another question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/41541/41372) I asked earlier this week.

Let's say that I want to find a set of matrices $S_i$, with $0\leq i\leq N$, that minimizes some objective function with numerous terms. I can easily compute the gradient of the objective function, with regard to each matrix. This provides me a system of equations where each matrix is linked to its immediate neighbours.

For example, in my case, we can write $S_i=F_i(S_{i-1}, S_{i+1})$, where $F_i$ is some function. We also have some conditions at the boundaries so $S_0$ and $S_N$ are fully determined.

In some sense, this is very similar to a 1D finite difference problem, except that the $S_i$ are matrices, not humble scalars.

For scalars, the problem is normally simple enough to write, for example as a linear problem with one big (and eventually sparse) matrix. There are many ways to solve this type of problem. However, for matrices, it can get quite challenging as matrices do not commute in general so the function $F$ can be more complex to linearize and write as a large matrix, especially if it also involves the inverse of some matrices $S_i$.

Is there any resource on how to solve these kind of problems? Or at least to reformulate it in a way that is more consistent with how people look at this type of problems? For now the best I can do is to solve each matrix from its neighbours over and over, so it takes a long time to eventually converge.

Comment: Are there any specific features for the function F or matrices S that can perhaps be exploited here?

Comment: This is meant to be a generic question, however to see the exact function $F$, it's linked in the first sentence of this question.