# Solution to minimization problem when variables factor in 2 analytical problems

Tags: iterative-method, matrix-equations

I am asking a follow up question to [this question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/41586/41372), but I could probably have written it as an answer instead. However, I don't know if what I am doing here makes sense or is too complicated for my problem so I am not sure it's the correct answer!

As I explained in the other question, I have basically a very standard unconstrained function minimization problem. Let's say that the function to minimize $F$ depends on 2 matrices ($A$ and $B$) and that I can compute the gradients $F_A$ and $F_B$. I could directly combine the gradients and use a standard solver but I know that I can solve the equations $F_A=0$ and $F_B=0$ analytically when only one variable is allowed to change. So I am wondering if there is a better approach to my problem.

More specificaly, let's assume without loss of generality that my iteration starts at $(0,0)$ and I am looking to find a better estimation of my minimum. I find $A_0$ and $B_0$ as the matrices that solve $F_A(A_0,0)=0$ and $F_B(0,B_0)=0$. Then I define an auxiliary function $f(x,y)=F(A_0x,B_0y)$ where $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$. The idea is that, as the Hessian is positive definite, an approximate minimum should happen for a certain value $0<x<1$ and $0<y<1$.

The reason why I use this auxiliary function is that it computes in a very straightforward way the value of my function on a much smaller manifold, with most dimensions aligned to the gradient at two points.

I can then compute:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\mathrm{tr}(A_0^TF_A(A_0x,B_0y)$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\mathrm{tr}(B_0^TF_B(A_0x,B_0y)$$
These functions are easy to compute, for example at the four corners of the square $(x,y)\in[0,1]^2$. This gives me $8$ values, with $2$ of them being zeros (they match the condition that $f_x(1,0)=f_y(0,1)=0$).

If I suppose that $f(x,y)$ is a conic section, I can write:
$$f(x,y)=\frac12ax^2+bxy+\frac12cy^2+dx+ey+g$$
And we can get the partial derivatives:
$$f_x=ax+by+d$$
$$f_y=bx+cy+e$$

There are some conditions on the values, for instance as $f_x(1,0)=a+d=0$ and $f_y(0,1)=c+e=0$, I can reduce to only $3$ variables. There are several ways to estimate these but in the end, it's just a simple $2\times2$ matrix linear problem.

Is it a standard approach, to assume that the solution to the bigger problem is simply the combination of two orthogonal partial solutions? I have honestly not seen this approach to solve minimization problems but it seems to make sense in my situation, as my earlier approach is really zigzagging between two minimum values. I still have to try it on my real data though.